# Py_NewInterpreter fatal error with ceval orphan tstate

Tags: python, c, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 for extending my C++ application with python.

And when two pthread of C is executing Py_NewInterpreter() it is throwing faltal error with ceval-orphan tstate.  There is no problem when sequential thread execution.

Let me know if any solution to be fixed in my python library.

Comment: Can you give more details? Have you tried creating a minimal example that reproduces the problem? E.g.: create two threads, call `Py_NewInterpreter` in each, and observe the crash.

Comment: i have tried creating minimal example.. but when the number of incoming threads are more, say,  after 15 threads  and still the 15 threads are not exit but i got 16+17th thread then it crashed..   but its not crashing for if i limit only 1 to 5 threads...

Comment: Can you tell me what will happen internally when invoking Py_NewIntepreter().  Will it create new memory area like (exec) or it will create a new interpreter all together with new GIL ?

Comment: All interpreters share the GIL because it also protects access to global objects shared by the interpreters, such as type objects created by C extensions.

Comment: am doing the sequence like... pthread->function1->In function1 create newIntepreter and do import and call the function in python by PyObject_callObject().   This sequence repeats for n number of times.. and somewhere am getting crash when calling newintepreter.  In this case, how to handle such flow ?

Comment: Have you found any solution?